# Regex - match variable beginned with $ in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match all the variables like `$bar, $foo`, I only have this until the moment:

```
(\$)+[A-Za-z]
```

Comment: Your `+` is in the wrong place. Your regex says "at least one `$`, then one letter"

Comment: You don't need `()` around `\$`.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. Are you trying to match a valid `php` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just this:

```
/\$[\w_]+/g
```

And if you want to check the variable does not start with number, just check by negative lookahead. (?![\d])

```
/\$(?![\d])[\w_]+/g
```

**/g** to match all.

Comment: What does the `_` do after the `\w`?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: some variables can contains _

Comment: Ah, I thought it was some option line `?` or `^`. Thanks!

Comment: @JackDuong \w is the same as [a-zA-Z0-9_] so you dont need the _ after \w

Comment: This will match `$123abc`, is that desired behaviour? Do these variable names come from javascript or what language is it?

Answer (score 1):

This should match some common valid variables which consists of [A-Za-z0-9_] but don't start with number.

```
/(\$(?!\d)\w+)/g

/ .. /g   // regular expression is put between two //, the g behind is flag for global
( .. )    // a capturing group, can be called using \1 or $1 depending on regex processor
\$        // escaped character `$`
(?!\d)    // negative lookahead - ensures that next character after $ isn't a match ->
    -> \d // matches one digit
\w+       // one or more "word characters". Matches the ASCII characters [A-Za-z0-9_]
```

note: if you are going to match all variable names globally, you don't need any capturing groups, so just use `/\$(?!\d)\w+/g`.

> According to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php), this is the right regexp: `\$+[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*`

***EDIT:** I have just noticed you are not matching PHP variables at all, but you get the idea now. :)*

For fun http://regex.alf.nu/

Comment: Good on you for explaining your regex, but isn't `^` the negation, not `!`? Or and I misunderstanding that?

Comment: Oh yes `[^x]` means everything except x, but negative lookahead says "if the next character doesn't match, then continue with regular expression". `lookaround`, be it `lookbehind` or `lookahead` don't ever match anything, they just check if there would be a match or not.

Comment: Oh, so that's just the syntax for the negative lookaround? That makes sense.

Comment: For the one from php.net you will probably want to have `\$` in front, since the OP seems to want to match that as well. The given one seems to just be for the name itself.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Yes of course, thanks. :) I have got lost in all those edits! Anyway `\$+` is more correct.

Comment: If PHP variables can have more than one $, then I suppose so. I've never actually used the language.

Answer (score 0):

```
\$[A-Za-z]+\w*
```

Explained: $ in the start, one or more letters, followed by 0 or more valid variable letters (depending on language).

See https://www.regex101.com/r/cB1bM1/1 for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Pretty sure `$abc123def` is valid.

Comment: shouldn't `$123abc` valid?

Comment: @SampathLiyanage No, a PHP variable can't start with number.

Comment: This is javascript (see the tag) @Qwerty

Comment: @SampathLiyanage Stupid me!

Answer (score 0):

The regex you may need is:

```
\$\w+
```

Comment: No, because this matches a blank string at the end of the line, afaik. Either that or flat-out doesn't work.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes \w doesnt't match whitespace